# Entity Framework Object State new / existing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I create a new object called person and I want to connect it to a record already in the database called address. When I go and save the Person object I don't want to insert the address a second time and create a duplicate. What is the best way to handle this with EF ?

Comment: After creating your person object , you simply set its adress member, the use add method , then save changes

Comment: yeah but I want to save(insert) the person record

Comment: simply use add(Person) method, and if there is a reference to person in address , you should update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the best way to do this is to set only the foreign key field, not the entire object.

For example,

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "John Doe";
p.AddressId = 12345;
context.People.Add(p);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here is a great article by Julie Lerman that explains why EF duplicates records.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Should note that this only works if the Person class has an AddressId property in addition to the Address navigation property.

Comment: if I have a address in the navigation property and in the id EF creates a duplicate

Comment: If the address is existing and the person is new, then the address navigation property shouldn't be set.  If you decide to set it via code, you have to tell EF that the address already existed or it will create a new one, regardless of whether you set the foreign key ID field.  The line in the article I referenced (context.Entry(topic).State = EntityState.Unchanged) is what is telling EF to ignore that existing address.  You should only set the ID field, not the navigation property to use the answer I provided.  Otherwise, you have to do as Julie suggests and manage the entity's state in code.

Comment: and you have to be in the context in order to set the state ?

Comment: "Entry" is a non-static method on DbContext, so you do have to have an instance of the context class in order to call it.